# Tridion Object Caching is not working with SDL Web 8.1.1 with DXA 1.4

Tags: content-delivery, web8, cache

We are trying to enable Tridion Object Caching with SDL Web 8.1.1 on DXA 1.4, but not able to cache objects.

We have enabled object caching in discovery service `cd_storage_conf.xml` at location:

```
<ObjectCache Enabled="true">
    <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">
        <Param Name="MemSize" Value="256mb"/>
    </Policy>
```

Also enabled cache on `ItemType` in discovery/session as below:

```
ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="true"
```

But still items are not cached in object caching.

We have not installed Cache Channel Service yet to invalidated items.

Please let us know where we are missing settings.

Comment: How do you know that object caching does't work? Note that it object caching is a feature of the CIS services and is not related to the Web Application.

Comment: Did you enable object caching only for Discovery Service? Not for Content Service?

Comment: I have enabled object cache in discovery and Session service both. I have not installed Cache Channel service, so ideally when Cache is on, all content should be cached, but when I publish any page/component from CMS it reflects immediately on CDA page on browser.

Comment: I think as we are using all static components on the page that is default provided by DXA and Tridion object caching is only cached dynamic objects which is available in Broker DB, But I don't understand why it is not cache whole page object as we configured all items to be cached?

Comment: Note that this is more a general CD question than a DXA question. Makes sense to reflect that in the Tags.

Comment: Why Tridion object caching is not cache pages, we are publishing all items in the Broker DB?